# Why does getting the address of certain linker variables halt SAMD21 execution in Rust with LLVM but not in C with GCC?

Tags: assembly, arduino, linker, rust

I'm trying to get my Arduino MKRZero working in Rust. I successfully blinked the LED, and my next step was to copy the global data from text into data.

I have the following linker variables defined:

**Rust**

```rust
extern {
    static __StackTop: u32;
    static mut __etext: u32;
    static mut __data_start__: u32;
    static mut __data_end__: u32;
    static mut __bss_start__: u32;
    static mut __bss_end__: u32;
}
```

**C**

```c
extern uint32_t __etext;
extern uint32_t __data_start__;
extern uint32_t __data_end__;
extern uint32_t __bss_start__;
extern uint32_t __bss_end__;
extern uint32_t __StackTop;
```

To cut a long story short, the Rust code

```rust
let mut pSrc: *mut u32;
pSrc = &mut __etext;
```

causes execution to halt i.e. the LED does not blink. Commenting out that line and proceeding to the code that zeros the BSS segment

```rust
let mut pDest: *mut u32;
pDest = &mut __bss_start__;
```

causes the blinker code to work just fine. As far as I can see, getting the address of the `__etext` linker variable halts execution but getting the address of `__bss_start__` is fine.

The C version of this has no problems at all:

```
  uint32_t *pSrc, *pDest;
  pSrc = &__etext;
  pDest = &__data_start__;
  // <fill pDest with pSrc>

  for (pDest = &__bss_start__; pDest < &__bss_end__; pDest++)
  {
      *pDest = 0;
  }
```

The linker scripts are identical for both pieces of code (and can be found in the repositories linked below). The C is compiled with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and the Rust with LLVM with this target JSON to pass to LLVM:

```
{
    "llvm-target"         : "thumbv6m-none-eabi",
    "data-layout"         : "e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64",
    "linker"              : "arm-none-eabi-gcc",
    "pre-link-args"       : [ "-nostartfiles", "-Tlayout.ld" ],
    "target-endian"       : "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "32",
    "arch"                : "arm",
    "os"                  : "none",
    "executables"         : true
}
```

See the `build.sh` scripts in each to see exactly the commands run.
The data layout was obtained from the command

```
clang --target=thumbv6m-none-eabi -S -emit-llvm empty.c -o empty.ll
```

The repository of C code is [here](https://github.com/djmcgill/c-to-the-moon) and the Rust code is [here](https://github.com/djmcgill/minimal-to-the-moon). The offending line is `src/main.rs:38`.

I've included the output of `arm-none-eabi-objdump -Cd` for 1) the C code, 2) the Rust code with the error line commented, and 3) the Rust code with the error line running. However I can't read assembly well enough to parse this to identify my error.

I suppose my next step would be to use LLVM for the C code instead of GCC to see if that's causing any issues, or just producing a C library from Rust and calling it in my C main. Attaching a debugger will be difficult on the MKRZero so I might have to buy a regular zero or some other SAMD21 breakout board and try it on that too.

Comment: can you disassemble (arm-whatever-objdump -D) the binary in question and show the specific values produced by the linker for those linker variables?

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be because Rust validates the pointer in some way and a pointer past the end of the `.text` section isn't valid.

Comment: I have updated the repository with the result of `arm-none-aebi-objdump -CD` for the [working](https://github.com/djmcgill/minimal-to-the-moon/blob/master/full-obj-dump-working) and [failing](https://github.com/djmcgill/minimal-to-the-moon/blob/master/full-obj-dump-not-working) code.